# SQL subtotals to each group without using RollUp and Grouping Sets

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I'm using SQL Server 2019. I've met a sudden trouble with creating  subtotals for each group in my table. I have a table which consists of more than 32 columns and more than 10000 rows which which produces  over 5000 groups. I've tried to use Rollups and Grouping sets but they have limitations - 32 columns of grouping expressions max and 4096 groups max. So I can't use these nice functions.

And yes it necessory to subtotal all of the columns no matter how much time will it take.

This is my sample table
[My sample table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2b574.png)  /  [Result I want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2xHBz.png)  - [DBFiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=01f0d40c3b27d981c7fa787eb2598454)

So is there a way to get rid of rollups and grouping sets? The last idea of mine is to use cursor and union table groups with result rows but I know there should be another way.

```
CREATE TABLE Tab1 (
  "Id" INTEGER,
  "P1" INTEGER,
  "P2" INTEGER,
  "P3" INTEGER,
  "P4" INTEGER,
  "P5" INTEGER,
  "P6" INTEGER,
  "P7" INTEGER,
  "P8" INTEGER,
  "P9" INTEGER,
  "P10" INTEGER,
  "D1" INTEGER,
  "D2" INTEGER,
  "D3" INTEGER,
  "D4" INTEGER,
  "D5" INTEGER,
  "D6" INTEGER,
  "D7" INTEGER,
  "D8" INTEGER,
  "D9" INTEGER,
  "D10" INTEGER,
  "F1" INTEGER,
  "F2" INTEGER,
  "F3" INTEGER,
  "F4" INTEGER,
  "F5" INTEGER,
  "F6" INTEGER,
  "F7" INTEGER,
  "F8" INTEGER,
  "F9" INTEGER,
  "F10" INTEGER,
  "E1" INTEGER,
  "E2" INTEGER
);

INSERT INTO Tab1
  ("Id", "P1", "P2", "P3", "P4", "P5", "P6", "P7", "P8", "P9", "P10", "D1", "D2", "D3", "D4", "D5", "D6", "D7", "D8", "D9", "D10", "F1", "F2", "F3", "F4", "F5", "F6", "F7", "F8", "F9", "F10", "E1", "E2")
VALUES
  ('101', '298', '341', '166', '130', '86', '23', '323', '134', '335', '304', '499', '128', '475', '398', '190', '290', '500', '123', '43', '285', '153', '399', '291', '75', '97', '428', '302', '421', '55', '119', '174', '344'),
  ('101', '430', '286', '207', '341', '415', '457', '350', '346', '97', '500', '431', '286', '86', '425', '74', '135', '474', '278', '75', '484', '387', '84', '265', '101', '493', '180', '176', '127', '498', '311', '184', '46'),
  ('101', '497', '123', '322', '479', '130', '443', '392', '206', '37', '198', '318', '38', '461', '43', '367', '476', '111', '31', '422', '234', '115', '495', '55', '361', '446', '205', '283', '239', '461', '419', '140', '305'),
  ('102', '496', '178', '294', '471', '469', '30', '66', '498', '491', '329', '497', '416', '175', '21', '356', '265', '146', '130', '450', '22', '226', '418', '390', '498', '303', '292', '177', '24', '345', '93', '232', '323'),
  ('102', '57', '442', '110', '70', '272', '431', '198', '52', '331', '448', '438', '171', '280', '115', '50', '28', '303', '468', '251', '465', '429', '70', '150', '330', '126', '60', '208', '325', '82', '81', '239', '162'),
  ('103', '444', '143', '119', '355', '246', '410', '144', '440', '71', '181', '418', '121', '162', '417', '149', '279', '344', '332', '169', '229', '416', '39', '246', '180', '399', '396', '334', '491', '399', '85', '468', '236'),
  ('103', '104', '163', '267', '110', '375', '396', '498', '182', '258', '254', '148', '397', '257', '407', '156', '255', '314', '215', '196', '416', '160', '231', '466', '207', '281', '383', '359', '244', '182', '445', '119', '371'),
  ('103', '199', '168', '483', '303', '443', '383', '463', '244', '221', '231', '496', '88', '182', '403', '178', '119', '242', '42', '424', '272', '243', '44', '178', '261', '335', '442', '340', '364', '441', '397', '331', '441'),
  ('103', '296', '222', '340', '472', '130', '138', '215', '261', '460', '283', '485', '108', '107', '373', '259', '227', '66', '386', '494', '99', '175', '197', '44', '406', '370', '263', '236', '478', '435', '468', '272', '240'),
  ('104', '385', '332', '333', '127', '194', '348', '364', '472', '333', '324', '95', '127', '491', '83', '283', '20', '445', '164', '258', '199', '340', '281', '484', '51', '151', '287', '480', '111', '447', '488', '496', '263');
```

Comment: While asking a question, you need to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example):
(1) DDL and sample data population, i.e. CREATE table(s) plus INSERT T-SQL statements. 
(2) What you need to do, i.e. logic and your code attempt implementation of it in T-SQL. 
(3) Desired output, based on the sample data in the #1 above.
(4) Your SQL Server version (SELECT @@version;).
All within the question, no images.

Comment: Do you mean you just wish to get a summary of the value for each column?  Somewhat unclear whet is meant by group here: " for each group"

Comment: I meen I want to get subtotals for each group. Table can be grouped by Id and I need subtotals of every column in the group from P1 to E2

Comment: Much easier to do it in your front end than your database.

Comment: Please don't use images for data, code or errors - use formatted text.

Comment: Yes I know that it will be much easier to use postprocessing outside of DB and SQL but this is my limitation I must format table such a way

Comment: Can you please add some expected output based on your sample data? This will help clarify what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: @lptr Thanx a lot that's great! but can you please explain me about sorting. It looses sorting within the group and column if some of the walues are 0 or null (https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=de8ed58f13206495cc74c66d8ccb8bae)

Comment: ..@Syngltake .. it should be lead instead of lag (lag marks the first p1 (order by p1) as last. If there are multiple max p1 values you could add p2 as tie breaker (and p3, p4 etc) if you would like to keep the order of the data as is (in the insertion) then you need a column (identity etc) that denotes order and then to order by that in lead(). `lead(id) over(order by id, p1,p2) = id ` .. f2 was sum(d2)..